# Cannot use object of type Google_Auth_LoginTicket as array

Tags: php, android, oauth-2.0

I was performing Google Sign in on Android Application for the first time. At the client side, I obtained the access token and sent to the PHP server via POST.

By referring to Google's Documentation, the code I used in backend is as follows:

```
$id_token = $_POST['id_token'];

$CLIENT_ID = "** MY WEB APPLICATION CLIENT ID **";

$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');

...

$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
    $userid = $payload['sub'];
} else {
    echo "Invalid Token";
}
```

When obtaining user id, the error is : **"Cannot use object of type Google_Auth_LoginTicket as array"**

I am pretty new to Google sign in. Please point out what all has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found It. I made some modifications to the code

```
$token_data = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token)->getAttributes();
$user_id = $token_data['payload']['sub'];
```

Now the user id is retrieved fine.